# fileInputstream method exception

Tags: java, grails, groovy, fileinputstream

I am trying to get my code to read an excel file from the local computer and it is giving me a method exception.

```
file f1 = new File("C://documents//test//testfile.xls")
path = f1.getAbsolutePath("C://documents//test//testfile.xls")
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);


Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static.com.genologics.client.bartender.midscript.file() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [C:\documents\test\testfile.xls]
Possible solutions: find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), with(groovy.lang.Closure), wait()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.genologics.client.bartender.midscript.file() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [C:\documents\test\testfile.xls]
Possible solutions: find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), with(groovy.lang.Closure), wait()
    at com.genologics.client.bartender.midscript.main(CSVandManifestGenerator.groovy:43)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have posted, your declaration for `f1` has `file` with a lowercase f. This is probably not the class you were interested in, but I may be mistaken. Capitalize the F  and you should be ok.

Also, you can do away with the `path` variable, as FileInputStream accepts a File object as a constructor parameter.